# Struct with bidimensional array malloc

Tags: c, arrays, struct, floating-point, malloc

Is it possible to `malloc` this struct in C?

```
typedef struct  {
    float a[n][M];
}myStruct;
```

I've tried different ways with no success.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What went wrong when you tried? (assuming n and M are properly defined).

Comment: all malloc would get is a `sizeof(float) * n * M` for the amount of memory to allocate. malloc couldn't care less, really, what goes inside the memory you're requesting. it just needs to know how MUCH memory you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `n` and `M` are compile time constants, you just want

```
myStruct *p = malloc (sizeof myStruct);
```

or

```
myStruct *p = malloc (sizeof *p);
```

If you actually meant *'how do I allocate an N x M array of a struct where n and M are not known at compile time'*, the answer is:

```
typedef struct {
   float x;
} myStruct;

...

myStruct *p = malloc (sizeof myStruct * M * N);
```

then access as `p[M * m + n]` where `0<=m<M`, `0<=n<N`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10
#define M 15

typedef struct {
    float a[N][M];
} myStruct;

int main(void)
{
    myStruct *m;

    m = malloc(sizeof(*m));
    printf("size = %zu\n", sizeof(*m));
    free(m);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it, i was using sizeof(m) instead of sizeof(*m) in the malloc, small things I didnt see, thank you!, and yes N and M are constants

Answer (score 0):

You need a double pointer, i.e. a pointer to an array of pointers, like this

```
typedef struct  {
    float **data;
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int columns;
} MyStruct;
```

then to `malloc()` it

```
MyStruct container;

container.rows    = SOME_INTEGER;
container.columns = SOME_OTHER_INTEGER;
container.data    = malloc(sizeof(float *) * container.rows);
if (container.data == NULL)
    stop_DoNot_ContinueFilling_the_array();
for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < container.rows ; ++i)
    container.data[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * container.columns);
```

dont forget to check `container.data[i] != NULL` before dereferencing and also do not forget to `free()` all the poitners and the pointer to array of poitners too.